# Problems keeping objects alive

Tags: c++

I've encountered a weird problem that doesn't make any sense to me.

I've a struct (that contains string) on an API defined as follows:

```
typedef struct sNCharcb
{
    char * pData;
    int    iDataLen;
}
tsNCharcb;
```

I need to save a deep copy of this struct. I have created an utility function to make a copy of this struct:

```
inline sNCharcb rapi_strcpy(const sNCharcb &rapistr)
{
    sNCharcb res;

    res.pData = new char[rapistr.iDataLen];
    strcpy(res.pData, rapistr.pData);
    res.iDataLen = rapistr.iDataLen;

    return res;
}
```

I create copies of those "sNCharcb" structs using this utility method and save them to reference variables in a parent object:

```
stored_sNCharcb = rapi_strcpy(sNCharcb_to_copy);
```

After a short while these stored values are magically changed to contain some random garbage. The parent object where these values are stored is inside the scope all the time and it's not destructed. What might be causing these values to get wiped prematurely?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not `std::string` instead?

Comment: You should probably implement meaningful copy constructors, assignment operator and destructor for this class. Or tag the question as C. Or just use an `std::string` data member instead of `char*` and all the problems disappear.

Comment: This is an API I cannot change. I have to play with the C strings whether I like it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the data in `pData` NULL terminated?  If not, the `strcpy` call in `rapi_strcpy` may be running off the end and therefore copying beyond size allocated in the target.

You probably want to be using something that forces a length, like `strncpy` or `memcpy`:

```
strncpy(res->pData, rapistr.pData, rapistr.iDataLen);
```

Comment: data should be NULL terminated, however I'll change the method as suggested. It's safer that way.

Comment: Data actually was not NULL terminated and rapi_strcpy was running off as you suggested and writing parts of memory it shouldn't touch. This caused the problem and changing strcpy method to strncpy to force length fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

> After a short while these stored values are magically changed to contain some random garbage.

Assuming that `stored_sNCharcb` is valid when `rapi_strcpy()` exits, and then `stored_sNCharcb` changes at a later time, that would suggest that code you have not shown is overwriting `stored_sNCharcb` when it should not be, such as due to a buffer overflow or such.  I suggest you put a data breakpoint on `stored_sNCharcb` after `rapi_strcpy()` exits, and then let the debugger tell you if it is being modified so you can see exactly which code is modifying it.

Comment: This proved to be a good way to diagnose the problem. It was buffer overflow indeed.